# How to remove invoice fee from Woocommerce order mail template?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, invoice

As the title says, I want to remove the invoice fee from the customer-processing-order.php (I Think this is the right template)
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/customer-processing-order.php

From what I understand it comes from the function `get_order_item_totals()`.
I can't just use CSS to hide it either because everything is inside a table. I found a website where someone was trying to hide the shipping cost and he used this:`unset($totals['shipping']);` inside the php file, which seemed pretty straightforward and clean. I wish you could just write something like `unset($totals['invoice']);` but unfortunately that's not the case.

Anyone got any ideas? I can't turn it off anywhere inside Woocommerce either.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a screenshot of what exactly you want to be removed? I don't have an "invoice fee" anywhere at checkout ...

Comment: Here's a screenshot of it. Of course this is from using Klarna Checkout. If you use Cash-on-Delivery, it won't show up. 

http://imgur.com/POVSVbU

Comment: I see, and guess this is a payment fee, not an invoice fee. Are you sure you don't have any fee at your Klarna plugin settings? Setting this to zero should remove it from checkout.

Comment: Yeah, but the funny thing is that when the customers are using Klarna it doesn't show up in the Klarna mail (good). However Woocommerce also sends out a confirmation email and in that one it says that they "have" to pay an invoice fee, despite being told before buying that there are no such thing. This causes unnecessary arguments between my client and his customers. Of course one solution would be to write like an info box saying that they should just ignore the invoice/payment fee, but I don't know. It would be nice to just write like `unset($totals['invoice']);` :)

Comment: try `unset($order['fee_lines']);` instead

Comment: Thanks, gonna try that one. I'll tell you if it worked :)